# Show Payment methods in cart page - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, cart

How to show payment methods in cart page in magento. Need the payment methods to work similar to checkout page. Is there any way to do it. Help me guys if there is a way.
Thank You.

Comment: by default paypal payment method will display in cart page.... if users select payment method in cart page , than where they will enter shipping address ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have payment methods on a cart page. Payment methods depend on billing/shipping address, since there are cases where based on address different methods are shown.

It gets even more complicated if we are talking about online payment methods, which should redirect to 3rd part payment gateway.